# "html to csv: what does it work for files from the same address?"

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to convert HTML files to CSV. I have seen several posts on the page but I cannot successfully use them.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
 Excel Volume Count Export
</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="rpt_volume_count.aspx?a=96&amp;id=156981555&amp;partial=" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
```

```
url = "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = soup.select_one("table.rpt")
```

This is one of the suggested codes, but in my case that I have thousands of files from the same address, naming as url the "http:...etc" path will not work of all the files since it is the same. I was wondering what that unique value that separates on

Comment: I wondering what the unique value that separates one file from another should be?

Comment: Clarification, please: Give us the URL you want to read from and describe the tables you want to obtain from that URL.

Comment: The tables are volume counts, per hour (or 15') of a day. The url is http://mhd.ms2soft.com/tcds/tsearch.asp?loc=Mhd&mod=

Comment: How do you make the page give you the individual tables?

Comment: I did not write a script for it, I get the tables ready. But I know that the script used the id (=1569.....) you can see in this line of the html file: <form method="post" action="rpt_volume_count.aspx?a=96&amp;id=156981555&amp;partial=" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">

Comment: Do you mean that you want to open that page every 15 minutes and then capture the contents of the table whose title is 'Station Data'? I'm asking because I haven't been able to get the HTML source code for the page easily.